# Returning certain variables from a function?

Tags: c++

I've been working on this program for the past few hours, after learning about functions on friday, and I'm not sure how to call specific variables from my function. In the code below I need to call the values that I calculate in the cash() function, these are; hundreds, fifties, twenties, tens, fives, toonies and loonies. Thanks. My question is how can I call the specific value from my function, the code below does not work.

```
int main()
{
//DECLARATIONS
int totalDollarAmount;
int hundreds = 0;
int fifties = 0;
int twenties = 0;
int tens = 0;
int fives = 0;
int loonies = 0;
int toonies = 0;

 //prompt for input
cout << "Please input a dollar amount: " << totalDollarAmount << endl;

hundreds = cash(hundreds);
hundreds = cash(fifties);
hundreds = cash(twenties);
hundreds = cash(tens);
hundreds = cash(fives);
hundreds = cash(toonies);
hundreds = cash(loonies);

cout << " The total number of Fifties is: " << fifties << endl;
cout << "The total number of Twenties is: " << twenties << endl;
cout << "The total number of Tens is: " << tens << endl;
cout << "The total number of Fives is: " << fives << endl;
cout << "The total number of Toonies is: " << toonies << endl;
cout << "The total number of Loonies is: " << loonies << endl;
return 0;
}//end main

//code function
int cash(int hundreds, int fifties, int twenties, int tens, int fives, int loonies, int toonies, int totalDollarAmount)
{
totalDollarAmount * 100;

hundreds = totalDollarAmount/10000;
totalDollarAmount = totalDollarAmount % 10000;

fifties = totalDollarAmount/5000;
totalDollarAmount = totalDollarAmount % 5000;

twenties = totalDollarAmount/2000;
totalDollarAmount = totalDollarAmount % 2000;

tens = totalDollarAmount/1000;
totalDollarAmount = totalDollarAmount % 1000;

fives = totalDollarAmount/500;
totalDollarAmount= totalDollarAmount % 500;

toonies = totalDollarAmount/200;
totalDollarAmount = totalDollarAmount % 200;

loonies = totalDollarAmount/100;
totalDollarAmount = totalDollarAmount % 100;
}//end function
```

Comment: Check out `struct` (or `class`) in your book.

Comment: There are several different problems with this code, none of which have any essential connection to what you're trying to do (which makes it more difficult to answer, normally, and a lot less useful in the future). So you would probably be better served finishing the function tutorial you're working on, then coming back with a more tightly-defined problem if and when you next need help.

Comment: Move your `//DECLARATIONS` section outside the `int main() {...}` scope. Variables are bound to a [scope](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_variable_scope.htm)

Comment: What is wrong with the code? The only errors I get are with the obviously not working attempt to call the values

Comment: @taoufik I know that they are bound, they are called from main into function, values stored in the variables inside the function and then when I get it working sent back to main

Comment: You can either declare the variables outside of all scopes (global) or pass on all relevant variables to `cash`.  The answer below explains that last approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has a few problems.

1. Your `cash` function accepts 8 parameters, whereas you are only passing one parameter in each of your function call.
2. Your `cash` function returns `int`, but inside the function you are not returning anything.
3. If you want to return many values from one function call, you can use a struct or class and return its values, else you need to pass the parameters by reference or by pointer.
4. You are using the wrong command to input a value to a variable. Use `cin` to input a value instead of `cout`.

One quick fix to your code can be something like changing your `cash` function to

`void cash(int &hundreds, int &fifties, int &twenties, int &tens, int &fives, int &loonies, int &toonies, int &totalDollarAmount)`

Then in your `main` function, do the following changes:

1. Change the prompt for input to

   ```
   cout << "Please input a dollar amount: ";
   cin >> totalDollarAmount;
   ```
2. Change the function calling to

   ```
   cash(hundreds, fifties, twenties, tens, fives, loonies, toonies, totalDollarAmount);
   ```

P.S. There might be still some logic problems inside your `cash` function, such as the first line `totalDollarAmount * 100;` which you never assign back to the variable. But those program logic I'll leave it to you to fix.

Comment: I did those fixes, but it gives me 0's for all of the values. So how would I pass by reference?

Comment: @johnbowtome the `&` signs indicate that the value needs to be passed by reference

Comment: @johnbowtome you never store any value to the `totalDollarAmount` variable. you need to use `cin`, instead of `cout` to store the value.

Comment: fixed that, but it still returns 0's

Comment: What is your input? If you input `7000` it will show `1` for fifties and `1` for twenties. Take a look at http://ideone.com/59ULel

Comment: huh, guess theres alot wrong with the program then, because I would expect 70 to give 1 50 and 1 20

Comment: yes, take a look at the first line of your `cash` function, it never assigns back the multiplied value back to the `totalDollarAmount` variable. Can try changing it to `totalDollarAmount = totalDollarAmount * 100;`.